# Jupyer notebook: Clicked 3 and all output is gone?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Apparently when you type 3 in jupyter notebook the focused cell is turned into markdown and all output is gone, incredible... Now all progress I've done for 20 hours is gone. Any way to fix this? If it's not fixable this is a huge fault in jupyter. No single button should be able to destroy the work like that.

Also in tab-view the cell is still working but nothing inside the document says it is, and I get no output.

Comment: Jupyter saves checkpoints in a hidden directory, maybe your data is still there...

Comment: @EvertW Last check point was long ago so it isn't there.

Comment: just to be more clear, is all your code gone or is only your output gone with your code in a markdown cell ?

Comment: @KaranShishoo The output is gone, when I typed 3 accidently it transformed it into a markdown cell.

Comment: cant you just change the cell back to a code cell (there is dropdown near the top for that) and execute the code in the cell again to get your output back ?

Comment: @KaranShishoo I did change it back but the output was gone. If I execute it again I have to run everything all over again.